# Pattern for Guava Splitter

Tags: java, split, guava, splitter

I need to split String by  comma or dot or backslach :

```
Pattern stringPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s+|,|\\\\|");
Splitter.on(stringPattern).omitEmptyStrings().split(description));
```

but this pattern don't work , what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct regex for comma or dot or backslash is `[.,\\]`, so in Java that's

```
Pattern.compile("[.,\\\\]")
```

I do like Olivier's suggestion of CharMatcher though.

Answer (score 9):

Why not use a [`CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html)?

```
Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf(",.\\")).omitEmptyStrings().split(description);
```

Given your simple problem, I don't think you need the regular expressions.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use string.split with the regular expressions. Following should work (I have not tried)

```
 description.split(",.\\")
```

Then do null check (as such splitter has extra api for the same).

Patterns are useful for identifying "groups". Any regular expression related splitting can be equally done with strings (instead of pattern)-that is not to discourage from using Guava!